VirtualBox RDP Connection Not Working
I have 2 PC's, one running Windows 10 Home, the other running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. On the Ubuntu machine I have VirtualBox installed, and I am running a Kali Linux virtual machine. I cannot connect to the Kali VM from my windows machine using the Remote Desktop app.  I get the following error:
Error code: 0x3334
Extended error code: 0x0
Activity ID: {a493deb7-ac09-4408-a8ca-587cabc30000}
I am able to connect to the Kali VM on the local Ubuntu machine using Remmina, an open source RDP app.
Some steps I have tried:

I have tried mstsc.exe, but that requires windows pro edition.
I changed the firewall setting on the ubuntu machine to allow port forwarding of port 3389.
I am able to ssh into the host machine no problem
When I use Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <IP-Address> -Port 3389 I get TcpTestSucceeded: True
I am unable to ssh into the Kali VM from the windows machine
I am unable to ssh into the Kali VM from the local ubuntu machine as well

Edit for clarification:

The computers are on the hardwired into the same network via a router. I have very limited access to the router, as it is a rental.

